# Upload Images to Firebase Using Camera Failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera, android-manifest

I'm trying to upload images to my Firebase. When I try to take a photo through the camera it presents me with the error toast. Does anyone know how to resolve this problem or at least delete the option to take an image using the camera and instead rely only on the gallery images?

```
public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Uri imageUri;
    String myUrl="";
    StorageTask uploadTask;
    StorageReference storageReference;

    ImageView close,image_added;
    TextView post;
    EditText description;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        // Initializing UI elements
        close = findViewById(R.id.close);
        image_added = findViewById(R.id.image_added);
        post = findViewById(R.id.post);
        description = findViewById(R.id.description);

        // Initializing storage reference from Firebase Storage, posts
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("posts");

        // Setting click listener for close button to redirect back to MainActivity
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Setting click listener for posting images button
        post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                uploadImage();
            }
        });
        // Starting crop image activity with a 1:1 aspect ratio, because then it looks good in gui
        CropImage.activity()
                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                .start(PostActivity.this);

    }

    // Helper method to get file extension from a Uri
    private String getFileExtention(Uri uri){
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
    }

    // Method that uploads the image to Firebase Storage and adds post data to Firebase Realtime Database
    private void uploadImage(){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Posting");
        progressDialog.show();

        if(imageUri!=null){
            // Creating a new storage reference for the image file
            final StorageReference fileReference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+
                    "."+getFileExtention(imageUri));

            // Upload the image file to Firebase Storage
            uploadTask = fileReference.putFile(imageUri);
            // If upload is successful, get the image URL and add post data to Firebase Realtime Database
            uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
                @Override
                public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                    return fileReference.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {

                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        // this if statement adds post to Real Time Database

                        // get the download URL of the uploaded image
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        assert downloadUri != null;
                        myUrl = downloadUri.toString();

                        // save post data to the Firebase database
                        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

                        // gets a unique key for the new post
                        String postid = reference.push().getKey();

                        // create a HashMap to hold the post data
                        HashMap<String,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("postid",postid);
                        hashMap.put("postimage",myUrl);
                        hashMap.put("description",description.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("publisher", Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid());

                        // add the new post to the database
                        assert postid != null;
                        reference.child(postid).setValue(hashMap);

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        // redirect the user to the MainActivity after the post is uploaded
                        startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    // if the upload fails, show a toast message with the error message
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            // if no image is selected, show a toast message indicating so
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Image Selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    // method that handles the result of image selection/cropping activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // The requestCode parameter is used to identify which activity returned a result.
        // For example, if multiple activities are started for different purposes, the requestCode can be used
        // to determine which activity returned a result.
        // The resultCode parameter indicates the result of the activity that was started.
        // RESULT_OK is returned if the activity was successful.


        // check if the request code and result code match with the ones for the image selection/cropping activity
        if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            // get the cropped image URI from the result
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            assert result != null;
            imageUri = result.getUri();
            // set the image view to display the selected/cropped image
            image_added.setImageURI(imageUri);
        } else{
            // if something goes wrong during the image selection/cropping process, show a toast message and return to the main activity
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }



    }
}
```

I tryed adding this to my AndroidManifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```